# Why cannot I make Vim (not gVim) fullscreen?

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows

I use Vim on windows (not gVim) because I think, that windows menu bar is ugly. So I use Vim, but I cannot fullscreen it. When I try it caps at cmd max size (1/4 size of screen) and won't be bigger.

Is there a way to either:

- make Vim fullscreen

or

- hide menu bar from gVim?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that it's not Vim that you can't fullscreen: Vim in terminal mode runs in a terminal emulator. On Windows I think you can't make the console go full screen so this is absolutely not related to Vim.

However if you want to remove the menu bar from gVim you can read [`:h 'guioptions'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27guioptions%27) and you'll find out that you can add this line to your `.vimrc` (or event better your `.gvimrc`) to do that:

```
set guioptions-=m
```

Comment: Thank you. So I will have to check how to set console window biggerm but I think, I will stick with gVim with menus disabled :)

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the size of any standard console window in Windows, including Vim.

1. Open the system menu by clicking the icon in the upper-left corner
   of the window (to the left of the window title) or pressing
   Alt+Space.
2. Select the Properties menu item.
3. In the Properties dialog, select the Layout tab.
4. Adjust the Screen Buffer Size and Window Size.

[image: Vim console windows properties]

In general, to widen the window, I adjust the Window Size Width. To make it less wide, I adjust the Screen Buffer Size Width. Editing in this way will prevent you from getting a horizontal scroll bar or having to edit both the values. For normal console apps I let the Screen Buffer Size be larger than the Window Size height to support scrolling vertically to see history, but that doesn’t apply to Vim, so you could use the same method above when changing the height.

The keyboard shortcut Alt+Enter can also be used to go into full-screen mode. This is also a standard Windows console feature, not Vim-specific.

Answer (score 1):

For the gVim part of the answer, there are a few things you can add to your `_vimrc`. `set guioptions -=m` will remove the menu bar, and `set guioptions -=T` will remove the toolbar (below the menu bar). If you're not using these, you may wish to speed up load times by not building the menus: you can add `let did_install_default_menus = 1` and `let did_install_syntax_menu = 1` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but In windows terminal specifically there's padding by default making vim not the full size of the terminal.
this can be changed In settings -> additional settings -> appearances: there's padding and a scrollbar visibility which can be disabled

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-) I miss dôme information to use your answer. Could you be more specific and add some détails to your answer?